# JlayeredPane Transparency setOpaque not working

Tags: java, swing, transparent, jlayeredpane

I am creating a simulation type application, I want one background layer and another layer on top for all of the animations. Im currently using JlayeredPanes but i cannot get the background on the top layer to show as transparent so I can see the background, any help is much appreciated, heres the code:

Background layer

```
public class SimBackground extends JLayeredPane{

private Model theModel;
private SimulationArea simulationArea;

public SimBackground(Model theModel){
    this.theModel=theModel;

    setBackground(new Color(0, 230, 0));
    setOpaque(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    setVisible(true);

}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for(int x=0;x<50;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<50;y++){

            g.drawRect((x*10), (y*10), 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Top layer

```
public class SimulationArea extends JLayeredPane {

private int SPEED = 100;
private Model theModel;
Timer timer;

public SimulationArea(Model theModel){

    this.theModel = theModel;

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    setLocation(0,0);

    setOpaque(false);
    setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    setVisible(true);

    //Swing Timer
    timer = new Timer(SPEED,new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            update();
            repaint();
            revalidate();
        }
    });     
}
private void update() {
    theModel.update();
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //test get 1 active object

    ArrayList<ActiveObject> activeObjects = theModel.getActiveObjects();
    //System.out.println(activeObjects.size());
    for(int i=0; i<activeObjects.size(); i++){
        ActiveObject activeObject = theModel.getActiveObjects().get(i);

        int x = activeObject.getCoordinates().getX();
        int y = activeObject.getCoordinates().getY();
        int size = activeObject.getSize();
        g2d.fillRect (x ,y , size, size);
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm missing here?

Comment: Wait, the top layer extends JLayeredPane? Sorry but this is confusing me to no end. Shouldn't your JLayeredPane be the bottom of all, the container that holds **all** layers? And none of the layers should extend JLayeredPane. JPanel or JComponent, yes, but not JLayeredPane. And you should be drawing in your JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method not in a JLayeredPane. And read the JLayeredPane tutorial because it doesn't look like you know how to use them yet. You can find it here.... [how to use layered panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: those are only the panes, I havent posted the code for the panel, if they dont extend JlayeredPane how am I able to create them in thier own class? I couldnt find any examples of them in their own class

Comment: You would use a single JLayeredPane, would likely not extend it, and you'd add objects that extend JPanel or JComponent to the single JLayeredPane. There are lots of examples of its use on this site, some written by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a JLayeredPane, but if you do need to use JLayeredPane in the future, you will want to read the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) since as per my comment you're not using them correctly at all. Instead I recommend that you simplify by doing all drawing in a single JPanel, drawing your background into a BufferedImage perhaps in the constructor, and then drawing that image and your sprites within the JPanel's paintComponent method.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimExample extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final Color BKGD_COLOR = new Color(0, 230, 0);
   private BufferedImage bkgrnd = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H,
         BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

   public SimExample() {
      Graphics2D g = bkgrnd.createGraphics();
      g.setBackground(BKGD_COLOR);
      g.clearRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
         for (int y = 0; y < 50; y++) {

            g.drawRect((x * 10), (y * 10), 10, 10);
         }
      }
      g.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      if (bkgrnd != null) {
         g.drawImage(bkgrnd, 0, 0, null);
      }

      // draw sprites here
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimExample mainPanel = new SimExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: This would mean drawing it over and over though would it not?

Comment: @user3081855: there's little cost to drawing the BufferedImage.

Comment: That's great, I originally did this but for some reason thought it would be better for performance to sperate the layers

Comment: @user3081855: for example.

Comment: Thank you, I just tested, I had the bufferedImage in icon and had problems with it previously thats why i abandoned this solution, but your solution works great thanks